# WWDC scholarship app requirements?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, developer-program

I am trying to apply for the WWDC 2015 scholarship. I have an app that record trails (like Runkeeper) that I'd like to submit for the scholarship (and submit it to the App Store). However, in the scholarship app requirements, it states that the app must tell something about the developer, and the app must have the developer's name as its name. However, the app that I'm trying to submit neither tells about me, nor does it have my name as its name. Does the scholarship accept these kind of apps? I could extend my app to include info about me. But does Apple allow submitting an app to the app store and modifying it so it abides the scholarship requirements? I'm sorry if my question sound stupid :)

Comment: Could you link to the requirements (or are they NDA protected)? What specifically about the requirements has you puzzled?

Answer (score 2):

The app needs to be an interactive CV/Resume that shows off your creative and technical ability, but also talks about your background and projects you've worked on. Submitting an app you've already made that serves another purpose isn't what they're looking for, though you can (and should) submit links to other pieces of software you've made in addition.

More detail is given in the scholarship requirements section 1: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/Scholarship-Guidelines-and-Terms.pdf

Good luck!

Comment: Could you link to where you determined these requirements? If it's NDA protected, then you could say that but I'd hate for people that have legitimate shipping apps to be discouraged from applying. What if the people Apple selected to judge the entries would see evidence of actual app store approval as better than a simple CV/Resume? It would demonstrate sustained ability to ship as long as the entrant was the sole developer or disclosed exactly who else helped with the app in question...

Comment: Updated the answer with a link.

Comment: @bmike "...but I'd hate for people that have legitimate shipping apps to be discouraged from applying." Do you mean you hate students who submit legitimate shipping apps to the scholarship, or you hate the people who discourage students who submit legitimate shipping apps, or do you mean you don't like that students who want to submit legitimate shipping apps be discouraged from doing that?:)

Comment: I'd hate for people to assume this answer is the story and for those people to be discouraged from applying. Basically, I feel everyone should apply that thinks they have a shot at it. I even don't hate on people that over read what I've written :-)

Comment: @bmike thank you, your comment is very inspiring. 